# Read csv files and skip first N rows in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to do the same as the below Pyspark script but in Scala:

```
source_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(sourcePath)
.zipWithIndex()
.filter(lambda x: x[1] > int(n_skip_rows))
.map(lambda x: x[0])

df = spark.read.csv(source_rdd, header=True, multiLine=True, quote='\"', escape='\"', ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=True, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True)
```

I tried it this way but I get overloaded method when executing spark.read.csv:

```
    val rdd = spark.read.textFile(sourcePath).rdd
      .zipWithIndex() // get tuples (line, Index)
      .filter({case (line, index) => index > numberOfLinesToSkip.toInt})
      .map({case (line, index) => index}) //get rid of index
    val ds = spark.createDataset(rdd) //convert rdd to dataset*/
 
    var df = spark.read.csv(ds, header=true, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=true, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=true)
```

The error stack trace is this one:

```
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (csvDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long], header: Boolean, quote: String, escape: String, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace: Boolean, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace: Boolean)
    var df = spark.read.csv(ds, header=true, quote="\\", escape="\\" , ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=true, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=true)``
```

Comment: Can you add an error stack trace? Without that it's not clear which method is overloaded. Also, why not read your CSV file using `spark.read.csv()`?

Comment: I just added the error stack trace to the question. `spark.read.csv()` alone doesn't have skip rows functionality, so I need to do it in a RDD first

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused because of minor differences in Spark and PySpark APIs. See, when you're using PySpark, you're passing the options as `**kwargs`, it's then interpreted as options of reading the dataset. But in Spark APIs of scala, you should do this with options:

```scala
val df = spark.read
  .options(Map(
    "header" -> "true",
    "quote" -> "...", // all the other options
  ))
  .csv(rdd)
```

The stacktrace also says the same, it says the only options (overloads) of the `csv` methods are:

- Either provide the file paths of your csv files
- Or pass the dataset
- Or a single file path